# Linq To Entity Error while checking the record if exist in database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am getting an error when trying to use linqsql query:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

Code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateGiftVoucher(FormCollection collection)
    {
        IVoucherRepository voucherResp = new VoucherRepository();
        IQueryable<Voucher> getVoucher = voucherResp.GetAllVouchers();

        //if (getVoucher.Where(x => x.Code == collection["Code"]).Count() > 0) {
        if (getVoucher.Any(r => r.Code == collection["Code"]))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Code", "Code Already Exists");
        } return View(); }
```

Voucher Repository

```
 public IQueryable<Voucher> GetAllVouchers()
    {
        return entity.Vouchers;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Linq query is translated to SQL, then executed on the database. But there is no SQL equivalent for `collection["Code"]`, so the query can't be translated to SQL, hence the error. In that case the fix is easy: just put the result of `collection["Code"]` in a local variable outside the query.

```
    string code = collection["Code"];
    if (getVoucher.Any(r => r.Code == code))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Code", "Code Already Exists");
    }
```

Comment: I had the same problem and the solution works but I don't understand why collection["Code"] won't work. collection["Code"] is of type String, isn't it? So why would it make any difference what I use in the Linq query?

Comment: @PaulK, `r.Code == code` is never directly executed by the CLR; it's compiled as an expression tree, which at runtime is translated to SQL and executed by the DBMS. There is no way to translate `collection["Code"]` to SQL, and even if there was, the DB wouldn't have access to `collection` anyway...

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to entities cannot evaluate the expression collection["Code"]. Try evaluating that expression before the query:

```
string code = collection["Code"];
if (getVoucher.Any(r => r.Code == code))
{
    ...
```